# How to keep context on url redirect?

Tags: java, url

I have an institutional site (http://www.exemple.com/user) and a web application (https://web.server.com/myApp/instUser).

The Apache is configured to do this redirection.

Is it possible in JAVA, when the user access the first url and redirect to second one keep the same url?

Comment: You mean in the browser address field? No, not with redirection. But you could use a reverse proxy instead. However it would not make sense to do this to  go from http to https.

Comment: Henry, thank you. I will looking for it. For this situation make a little bit sense because i have a client service that others clients could use it, but the company name is a url path.

Answer (score 0):

response.sendRedirect(url); can be used from HttpServletResponse.